# Ignoring random effects when few data points are correlated

Tags: regression, mixed-model, epidemiology

Suppose we have covariates $X_{ij}$ and responses $Y_{ij}$ where there is correlation in the response with the same $i$. This amounts to the data being correctly modelled by a mixed effects models, with random effects of the group $i$:
$$
Y_{ij} = \beta^\top X_{ij} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij}, \quad \quad \epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2), \alpha_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_B^2).
$$
My question is: If there are only few data points that are correlated (say for most values of $i$, there is only one observation $j$, for others maybe $2$ or $3$ observations $j$), can we say something general on the effect of ignoring the correlation, and fitting an (misspecified) OLS model instead? E.g. that hypothesis tests on $\beta$ loose power or level?

Reasons to ignore the correlation could be e.g the lack of tradition for mixed models in some fields, or the easyness of theoretically analyzing the closed form solutions from OLS compared to less tractable REML estimates of mixed models.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your question is ? Small cluster sizes do not remove the need to control for the non-independence within clusters. If you really don't want to fit random intercepts for the groupID then you can fit fixed effects for it instead. On the other hand if the correlations within clusters is extremely small then you may be justified in ignoring it altogether.

Comment: But if cluster sizes are very small, I guess fitting fixed effects will require very many degrees of freedom. My question is to whether we can say something in general about the effect of the misspecification -- but maybe the answer is just no, unless very weak correlations, in which case the effect of misspecification has very little effect.

Comment: You are right that fitting fixed effects instead of random effects has the downside of consuming more degrees of freedom, but that is related to the number of clusters, not the cluster sizes. If you have 10 clusters are you fit fixed effects for them, you consume 10 degrees of freedom.